# Accessing URL without Port

Tags: windows-server-2008, email, iis-7

I have managed to install a mail service on my server (Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7). Currently it can be accessed through https://mail.mydomain.info:8000. I would like to access it without specifying the port no e.g. https://mail.mydomain.info. Can anyone direct me what kind of configuration I should set up (in the IIS or DNS or elsewhere) ?

Comment: If you want to access it without specifying the port then it needs to run on port 80 for HTTP or port 443 for HTTPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the default port of HTTPS is 443, you should configurate your web mail service to listen port 443 with SSL in IIS 7. You can follow [this guide](https://superuser.com/questions/72620/how-to-change-listening-port-on-webbserver-iis-7) to change port in IIS 7.

Comment: Port 443 has been used by my other website (myapp.domain.info). Is it still possible to access my mail without specifying the port 8000 ?

Comment: It is still possible to use port 443 if you have more than one IP address. You can assign more than 1 IP in a single network interface, or you can have multiple network interface. Assign myapp.domain.info to the first IP, and then mail.domain.info to the second one. It is also possible to use single IP with wildcat SSL but it is a bit costly.